# Logout function in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have some AuthService in services in ionic 3, that have function logout

**auth.service.ts**

```
export class AuthService {) { }  
  logout() {
   Alert('User is logging off..');
  }
}
```

The problem is that i must use that function in my header, that is repeated in every page

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      <img class="header-logo pull-left" src="assets/img/logo.jpg" alt="">
      <ion-icon name="log-out" class="pull-right logout-action" (click)="logout()"></ion-icon>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

What i need is that i can use that function every in my pages and not to import service and create function in every page

Answer (score 1):

Add logout button in the footer and put it into **app.html** as below:

```
<ion-footer>
   <button ion-button round (click)="logout()">LOGOUT</button>
</ion-footer>
```

Also, add following code in app.component.ts file:

```
constructor(){}
logout(){
   alert("This is logout");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shared component in this case, which is tightly coupled with the service and the function.

Add the component in your pages , so that it will be always shared.

Comment: Can you make a simple example

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you need:

1. Create a custom component ( or whatever name you want) that encapsulates your header (the template of the component will be the code snippet that you provided) and implements the **logout** function. Use the  on each page you need. Also this way you can reuse some code and your HTML will be cleaner.
2. Service solution(that you avoid): Create a service/provider that implements your **logout** method. Inject the service created where you need.
   Note: You should mark the injected service as **public** in the constructor to be accessible from template as **serviceName.logout()**.

Both solutions should work as you expect to, but you may think about moving the logout button into a parent component **or** create a side menu **or** create a dedicated page for user profile with logout, change password, etc.